# Legend for only specific datasets - chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to only have a legend label for only two of my three datasets in my chart.js stacked bar chart.

Is there a way to do this? At the moment I am only able to hide the entire legend by putting the following in my chart options:

```
legend: {
  display: false
}
```

I.e. would it be possible to specify which datasets have a legend and which don't in the options? (or in the datasets if that's possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter on the labels of the legend to filter out the datasets you dont want to show in the legend, see example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      },
      {
        label: 'dont show this',
        data: [17, 1, 15, 18, 13, 17],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (legendItem, chartData) => (legendItem.text !== 'dont show this')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration